# How to register for reCAPTCHA v3 site key for mobile app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

```
   Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');
  runApp(App());
}
```

I'm trying to upload a photo in Firebase Storage and it keeps running an error because of App Check. It says I need to configure it using the format above. How will I register my app for a recaptcha key?

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963043/9960358

Comment: It does not answer this question as this is for a mobile app and not web. I am facing the same problem and circled back to the webpage where this question came from.

Comment: Did you find how to solve this?